# Qual a diferença entre criar um Context com DbContext e DataContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, terminologia

Qual a diferença entre criar um Context com DbContext e DataContext?
Existe alguma diferença de performance ou melhores praticas entre um ou outro?

Veja os exemplos abaixo;

```
namespace _DBContext.DBase.Banco
{
    public class dbContext : using System.Data.Entity.DbContext
    {
        public dbContext()
            : base("EntityConn")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<dbContext>(null);
        }

        public DbSet<Tabela_DocsIten> Tabela_DocsIten { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="MeuBD")]
public partial class ModeloColDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{
    public System.Data.Linq.Table<Tabela_DocsIten> Tabela_DocsItens
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<Tabela_DocsIten>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`DbContext`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.103).aspx) representa uma combinação dos padrões [*Unit-Of-Work e Repository*](http://pazotto.com/posts/implementacao-dos-design-patterns-unit-of-work-e-repository-com-asp-net-mvc-e-ent) e permite consultar um banco de dados e agrupar as alterações que serão gravadas de volta ao armazenamento como uma unidade. `DbContext` é conceitualmente semelhante ao `ObjectContext`.

Comumente usado com um tipo derivado que contém `DbSet<TEntity>`, esses conjuntos são inicializados automaticamente quando a instância da classe derivada é criada.  Esse comportamento pode ser modificado aplicando o atributo `SuppressDbSetInitializationAttribute` a qualquer classe de contexto derivada ou a propriedades individuais na classe.

[**`DataContext`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx) representa o ponto de entrada principal para o LINQ to SQL framework. O `DataContext` é a fonte de todas as entidades mapeados em uma conexão de banco de dados. Ele controla as alterações feitas a todas as entidades recuperadas e mantém um "cache de identidade" garante que as entidades recuperadas mais de uma vez é representados por usando a mesma instância de objeto.

Em geral, uma instância `DataContext` é projetada para durar por uma "unidade de trabalho" no entanto, o aplicativo define esse termo. `DataContext` é leve e não é caro criar. Um típico LINQ to SQL aplicativo cria `DataContext` instâncias no escopo de método ou como um membro das classes de curta duração que representam um conjunto lógico de relacionadas a operações de banco de dados.

Referências:

- [DBContext](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/dbcontext-vs-objectcontext.aspx)
- [Understanding the DataContext](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/11/understanding-the-datacontext/)

Comment: Então é melhor usar DataContext do que usar Dbcontxt ?

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod, isso depende. Ninguém pode definitivamente dizer que um é melhor que o outro, pois depende do seu projeto, perguntas do tipo: "Qual é o tamanho/orçamento de seu projeto? Quantos desenvolvedores trabalharão nele?", devem ser levadas em consideração. Deixei na resposta, o que está escrito na documentação =)

Comment: Muito interessante sua ultima referencia.

Answer (score 2):

O [DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) é uma classe mais recente e representa uma combinação dos padroes de Unidade De Trabalho e Repositorio e pode ser usado para realizar queries no Banco de Dados.

O [DataContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx) é uma classe mais antiga e representa o ponto de entrada para a realizacao de LINQ to SQL.

Podemos utilizar os dois, porem como voce esta utilizando o EF voce deve utilizar o DbContext. Na pratica o auto complete fica muito mais simplificado (menos atributos que o DataContext + os seus atributos dos dominios) utilizando o DbContext comparado com o DataContext. [Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471455/is-dbcontext-the-same-as-datacontext)